# Bluetooth intent permission denied

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I am trying to pass the intent mentioned below but i am getting the following exception below . Anyone have any idea about this????

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra(BluetoothProfile.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE, prevState);
intent.putExtra(BluetoothProfile.EXTRA_STATE,BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED);
intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, mdevice);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED from pid=10459, uid=10126**

Answer (score 0):

do u have added permission in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: yes i aded both the permissions  
 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` is a protected intent which can and should only be broadcast by Android. You cannot broadcast protected intents.

This is mainly to protect recievers of this intent from recieving spurious intents from apps that cannot change the state of Bluetooth headset.

Why do you want to send this intent when you have not changed the state?

Comment: actually i am developing an apk with which i want to make the state of the device as STATE_CONNECTED but i am not connecting any other device or headset . I just want to make the state as STATE_CONNECTED .

Comment: but dont you think all the apps that are recieving this intent will try to open the connection as soon as state connected is recieved but might as well crash because it is not actually connected

Comment: It is for this same reason that you cannot broadcast new Message intent, new call intent , new connectivity intent. Because of one app there is a chance that all apps might crash or even lose data

Comment: If it is a protected intent and can only be broadcasted by android , then there must b a way to force the system to broadcast that intent at the framework level or RIL layer??????

Comment: Yeah,, connect a bluetooth headset it will broadcast :)

Comment: in that case do i have to force at the framework to broadcast that intent  ?? :P

Comment: yeah, if you have control on that then you can always sign your apk with platform certificate and add shareduserid to system, you can use the above code in your app itself

Answer (score -1):

Did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

in your manifest ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />